# Is there any way to express $f(x)$ in terms of $x$, or plot a graph of $f(x)$ with respect to $x$ from these equations?

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals

The equations available to me are:

$$f(x) = \int_{0}^{x}f(u) · f(2x-u)  du$$
$$ \int_{0}^{∞}f(x) dx = 1$$
$$f(0) = 0$$

I am unfamiliar with differential equations, and therefore did not know where to start for this.

Is it possible to state a relationship between $f(x)$ and $x$ purely in terms of a single variable, $x$? This can include an equation, or a graph.

Comment: Do you know how to differentiate the RHS?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: Can you relate the RHS with the convolution of f and f evaluated at $2x$, if yes then taking the laplace transform will give some hint, which will give the equation $L(2x) = \sqrt{L(x)}$, with $L(0) = 1$, which tell us $1/\ln(L)$ is linear

Comment: What does $L(x)$ refer to? I am still a bit new to calculus and am unfamiliar with Laplace transforms too

Comment: $L$ is the laplace transform

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137679/discussion-between-you-will-not-know-and-oakss).

Comment: Are you sure there *is* a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not think there is a solution unless one of the conditions is relaxed.

Let $u=2v$ in the RHS integral, then we have

$$\tag{1}
f(x)=2\int\limits_0^{x/2}dv \ f(2v)f(2(x-v))
$$

Let $f(2x)=g(x)$, then

$$\tag{2}
g(\frac{x}{2})=2\int\limits_0^{x/2}dv \ g(v)g(x-v)=\int\limits_0^xdv \ g(v)g(x-v)
$$

The second equality on the right is because the integrand is symmetric around the point $v=x/2$, which is done so that the integral is a Laplace convolution. Now take the [Laplace transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform) (henceforth LT) of (2). This yields

$$\tag{3}
2G(2s)=G(s)G(s)
$$

Where $G(s)$ is the LT of $g(x)$. By definition of the LT, we have

$$\tag{4}
G(s)=\int\limits_0^\infty dx \ e^{-xs}g(x)\\
\therefore G(0)=\int\limits_0^\infty dx \ g(x) = \int\limits_0^\infty dx \ f(2x)=\frac{1}{2}\int\limits_0^\infty dx \ f(x)
$$

The condition $\int\limits_0^\infty dx \ f(x)=1$ means that we must have $G(0)=1/2$, while (3) demands $G(0)=0$ or $G(0)=2$ so we have reached an inconsistency, and there is no solution. One could argue that the LT does not exist, so this argument is not valid, but given that $\int\limits_0^\infty dx \ f(x)=1<\infty$, the LT converges at least for $\Re(s) \geq 0$.

Suppose that we relax the condition $\int\limits_0^\infty dx \ f(x)=1$. We then face the functional equation (3) for which a general solution is unlikely. Letting $G(s)=e^{cs}H(s)$, we see that $H(s)$ satisfies the same functional equation (3) as $G(s)$, so the solutions are not unique. Using this form, one solution is $G(s)=e^{-as}$, whose inverse LT is $g(x)=\delta(x-a)$, which is Dirac's delta. Finally, one (formal) solution for $f(x)$ that satisfies the integral equation and the condition $f(0)=0$ is

$$
f(x)=2\delta(x-a) \qquad,\qquad a>0
$$